# Random walk on a sphere along latitude-longitude grid

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Suppose a sphere is partitioned by a latitude-longitude grid, with
grid quadrilaterals $\Delta \times \Delta$.
All grid nodes have degree $4$, while the North & South poles have
degree $2 \pi / \Delta$, with incident grid triangles.

Let a random walk from any grid node $p$ take one step
along each an incident arc, each with equal probability.
Here is a $1000$-step random walk starting from the North pole,
with $\Delta = 10^\circ$.

---

[image: RandWalkSphere1000]

---

In this example, the north pole is visited $20$ times.
My question is:

> ***Q***. What is the distribution of visits to the grid nodes 
>   (as a function of $n$, the number of steps, and $\Delta$)?
>
> ***Qa***. Specifically, how many visits to each pole can be expected (starting anywhere)?
>
> ***Qb***. Are the nodes closer to the poles (excluding the poles themselves)
>   visited more frequently than those near the equator?

Clearly the poles are visited frequently.
In a trial of $n{=}10000$ steps, $\Delta = 10^\circ$, the north pole was visited $195$ times.
Although I expected the answer to ***Qb*** to be *Yes*, I am not observing clear evidence of
such a bias.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the general theory any irreducible finite state space Markov chain has a unique stationary measure, and the empirical frequencies along a.e. sample path converge to this measure. The chain you consider is what is called the **simple random walk** on the constructed graph (the transition probabilities are equidistributed among neighbors), and its stationary measure is proportional to vertex degrees, which are $2\pi/\Delta$ for the poles and 4 for all other vertices.

Alternatively, one can obtain this measure from looking at the "latitudinal part" of the random walk, which is just the random walk on the integer interval $[0,\pi/\Delta]$ with the transition probabilities $p(i,i\pm 1)=1/4, p(i,i)=1/2$ and reflecting barriers at the endpoints. The stationary measure is then obtained by normalizing the vector $(1,4,4,\dots,4,4,1)$.

So, in your example with $\Delta=\pi/18$ the asymptotic frequency of the North pole should be $1/[2+4\cdot 17]=1/70$, which, for some reason, is much less than your empirical frequency $195/10000$.

Comment: I am seeing at the poles roughly about $36/4=9$ times the mean excluding the poles ($36 = 360^\circ/\Delta$). So I think that one quoted simulation may be misleading. A 2nd $10^4$ run led to $159$ & $117$ at the two poles, very close to $1/70$.